# Accessing House of Graphs data

Tags: graphs-and-networks, webservices

[House of Graphs](https://hog.grinvin.org) is a fun little website that provides access to a number of interesting graphs. Unfortunately it doesn't have a readily-accessible API.

Can I still get access to the data underneath?

Answer (score 11):

I did this one by [request from Szabolcs](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2263/request-useful-apis-for-which-to-build-serviceconnections?cb=1#comment9827_2263). It was a little tough and my implementation is still only in the 1.0.0 stage, but if the demand is there I can polish up the parts of it that remain too rough. To get started, we can install the `ServiceConnection` like so:

```
PacletInstall[
 "ServiceConnection_HouseOfGraphs",
 "Site" -> 
  "http://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer"
 ]
```

[image: asdasdasd]

You can read through my template notebook [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.services/ServiceConnections/HouseOfGraphs.nb) but I'll hit some of the highlights

Now we can `ServiceConnect` and get to work:

```
$hog = ServiceConnect["HouseOfGraphs"]
```

[image]

And see the requests I cooked in:

```
$hog["Requests"]

{"Authentication", "BasicSearch", "DownloadGraph", "GraphImage", \
"GraphInfo", "ID", "Information", "InvariantDefinition", \
"LastRequest", "ListInvariants", "Name", "RawRequests", \
"RequestData", "RequestParameters", "SearchParameters"}
```

Of these the one with the most support is the `"BasicSearch"`:

```
res = $hog["BasicSearch", "invariantId" -> "Claw-Free", 
  "invariantValue" -> True]
```

[image: blah]

```
res["Graphs"] // Normal

{<|"id" -> "46", "NumNodes" -> 7, "NumEdges" -> 16|>, <|"id" -> "44", 
  "NumNodes" -> 7, "NumEdges" -> 15|>, <|"id" -> "54", 
  "NumNodes" -> 7, "NumEdges" -> 18|>, <|"id" -> "58", 
  "NumNodes" -> 7, "NumEdges" -> 21|>, <|"id" -> "50", 
  "NumNodes" -> 7, "NumEdges" -> 17|>, <|"id" -> "26", 
  "NumNodes" -> 7, "NumEdges" -> 16|>, <|"id" -> "62", 
  "NumNodes" -> 5, "NumEdges" -> 0|>, <|"id" -> "52", "NumNodes" -> 4,
   "NumEdges" -> 0|>, <|"id" -> "56", "NumNodes" -> 7, 
  "NumEdges" -> 20|>, <|"id" -> "64", "NumNodes" -> 6, 
  "NumEdges" -> 0|>}
```

You can specify the search `"Mode"` but in general it tries to auto-detect that based on the parameters you pass. You can find the supported modes like so:

```
Keys@$hog["SearchParameters"]

{"InvariantValue", "InvariantClass", "InvariantRange", \
"InterestingFor", "WithName"}
```

And the supported arguments for each `"Mode"` like:

```
Keys@$hog["SearchParameters"]["InvariantRange"]

{"invariantId", "invariantValueFrom", "invariantValueTo"}
```

etc.

This is actually implemented by scraping the results page for a search (I couldn't find the equivalent of `"format=json"`). These values I find by parsing the `XMLObject` of the results. To determine what the parameters were valid I did a similar thing for the primary search page:

```
xml = Import[
   "https://hog.grinvin.org/StartNewSearch.action", {"HTML", 
    "XMLObject"}];
Merge[
 Cases[xml, 
  XMLElement["form", 
    {___, "id" -> i_, ___},
    e_
    ] :>
   i ->
    Association@Cases[e,
      XMLElement["select", {___, "name" -> name_, ___}, o_] :>
       name ->
        Association@
         Cases[o, 
          XMLElement["option", {___, "value" -> v_, ___}, {oname_}] :>
            ToLowerCase[oname] -> v, \[Infinity]
          ],
      \[Infinity]
      ],
  \[Infinity]
  ],
 Merge[Apply[Join]]
 ]
```

Then I cooked this into my service connection (see the template I liked to for more details) so that we can pretend we have a REST API.

Once you have a graph you can get its properties with `"GraphInfo"`:

```
info = $hog["GraphInfo", "id" -> res["Graphs", 1, "id"]]
```

[image]

And you can turn this into a proper `Graph` via the `"matrix"` structure:

```
AdjacencyGraph@Normal@info["Structures", "matrix"]
```

[image: blah]

Or we can get the `"GraphImage"`:

[image: img]

Note that in general unless I've implemented the scrape a request will just return the `XMLObject` for a page. You can always scrape that yourself, though:

```
Cases[
   $hog["ListInvariants"], 
   XMLElement[
     "a", {"shape" -> "rect", 
      "href" -> l_?(StringStartsQ["/ShowInvariant"])}, {tag_}] :>
    tag -> ToExpression@Lookup[URLParse[l, "Query"], "id"],
   \[Infinity]
   ] // Association // Sort

<|"Acyclic" -> 1, "Average Degree" -> 2, "Bipartite" -> 3, 
 "Chromatic Number" -> 4, "Clique Number" -> 5, "Connected" -> 6, 
 "Diameter" -> 7, "Edge Connectivity" -> 8, "Girth" -> 9, 
 "Maximum Degree" -> 10, "Matching Number" -> 11, 
 "Minimum Degree" -> 12, "Minimum Dominating Set" -> 13, 
 "Number of Edges" -> 14, "Number of Vertices" -> 15, "Radius" -> 16, 
 "Regular" -> 17, "Independence Number" -> 18, 
 "Algebraic Connectivity" -> 19, "Chromatic Index" -> 20, 
 "Index" -> 21, "Laplacian Largest Eigenvalue" -> 22, 
 "Second Largest Eigenvalue" -> 23, "Smallest Eigenvalue" -> 24, 
 "Longest Induced Path" -> 25, "Number of Components" -> 26, 
 "Number of Triangles" -> 27, "Eulerian" -> 28, "Hamiltonian" -> 29, 
 "Vertex Connectivity" -> 30, "Longest Induced Cycle" -> 31, 
 "Genus" -> 32, "Claw-Free" -> 33|>
```

*(Note that I just implemented this in the paclet so you'll actually get a good result from `$hog["ListInvariants"]` now)*

Hope this is useful and let me know if you have questions.